# PHPMailer doesn't send any mails

Tags: php, phpmailer, contact-form

I am using PHPMailer on my Website but it doesn't work.
In my normal code could not be any error because it already had worked.
I think the error is in htaccess because i use it to remove the .php in the url but i excluded the PHPMailer.php file.

This is the error log:

```
[20-Jan-2019 17:11:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(PHPMailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/kd41443/public_html/impressum_und_kontakt.php on line 235
[20-Jan-2019 17:11:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'PHPMailer.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/kd41443/public_html/impressum_und_kontakt.php on line 235
[20-Jan-2019 17:11:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(PHPMailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/kd41443/public_html/impressum_und_kontakt.php on line 235
[20-Jan-2019 17:11:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(PHPMailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/kd41443/public_html/impressum_und_kontakt.php on line 235
[20-Jan-2019 17:11:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'PHPMailer.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/kd41443/public_html/impressum_und_kontakt.php on line 235
[20-Jan-2019 17:13:09 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /home/kd41443/public_html/impressum_und_kontakt.php:242
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/kd41443/public_html/impressum_und_kontakt.php on line 242
```

Maybe a mistake in the .htaccess file?

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index$ "https\:\/\/www\.kruemelopment\-dev\.de\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kruemelopment\-dev\.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.kruemelopment\-dev\.de$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.kruemelopment\-dev\.de\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kruemelopment\-dev\.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.kruemelopment\-dev\.de$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^bilder\/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.kruemelopment\-dev\.de\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^errorpages$ "https\:\/\/www\.kruemelopment\-dev\.de\/" [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /errorpages/error404.html
ErrorDocument 401 /errorpages/error401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errorpages/error403.html
ErrorDocument 400 /errorpages/error400.html
ErrorDocument 451 /errorpages/error451.html
ErrorDocument 503 /errorpages/error503.html
ErrorDocument 504 /errorpages/error504.html
ErrorDocument 505 /errorpages/error505.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^screenshots$ "https\:\/\/www\.kruemelopment\-dev\.de\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !PHPMailer\.php
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats not the full error message.

Comment: PD of [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](//stackoverflow.com/q/24644436) (applies when not configuring any specific transfer/gateway).

Comment: @tom use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
Why to include 1 file twice?

Comment: @PratikCJoshi the `use` line doesn't include anything.

Comment: Thats the full log xD

Comment: Oh okay i will remove the use line

Comment: How did you install PHPMailer? It looks like either it's not fully installed, or your autoloader isn't set up.

Comment: I only downloaded the file I don't know how to make it with an autoloader because I host my website at non-own servers

Comment: @Tom, in what directory do you have `PHPMailer.php`? It looks like it isn't in the same directory as `impressum_und_kontakt.php`

Comment: it is. they are both in public_html directory

Comment: Are you developing on a Windows machine? Then check the EXACT lettering of your file names. Lower- and uppercase differences don't matter on Windows but will throw an error on Linux

Comment: everything is correct and yes i have linux

Comment: How did your error log change from _PHPMailer can't find it's exception class_ to _your script can't find PHPMailer_? You've definitely broken something else in the meantime.

Comment: It’s common to not be able to run composer directly on shared servers, but the simple workaround is to run it locally and upload the vendor folder it generates. This is described in the readme.